# Textwidth wrong after wrapfigure

Tags: wrapfigure, mdframed

I have included a picture with `wrapfigure` and everything is fine - the problem is that in my next formula environment, the formula is totally wrong! It seems to me, that the width which I set in the `wrapfigure` environment also effects the formula. How can I set the width back again to standard?

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{mdframed}

\newtheoremstyle{mystyle}{}{}{}{}{}{}{0.5em}{}
\theoremstyle{mystyle}
\newmdtheoremenv{formel}{Formel}

\begin{document}
\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{8cm}
  \includegraphics[scale=0.48]{example-image-a}
\end{wrapfigure}
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
\begin{formel}[Formel]
$1+1=2$
\end{formel}
\end{document}
```

So the text wrapping around the figure is OK, but then width of the formula is wrong. It seems to me, that `textwidth` is set to the `wrapfigure`'s `textwidth`, what results in a wrong display.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Your MWE contains a couple of typos (e.g., "docuemnt") and generates some option clashes. Please edit your MWE to eliminate these problems, so that it becomes compilable -- and still generates the error you're trying to fix. Please also consider eliminating all code that's not pertinent to the problem you're facing, so as to make the example code truly "minimalist". At the moment you're loading lots and lots of packages that don't seem to be related to the problem.

Comment: Just a note: `\usepackage{mwe}` and `\includegraphics[scale=0.48]{example-image-a}` make your MWE compilable without using your `picture.png` (which is not generally available). See also [New support package for MWEs](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/2470/6865).

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please register your account. Since you got a responses below that seems to answer your question (if it does not, please tell us!), please consider marking it as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below its vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). Additionally it is possible to upvote answers (with the upward pointing arrow to the left of it).

Answer (score 5):

To cite the manual of the [wrapfig](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/wrapfig) package, page 1:

> You must not specify a `wrapfigure` in any type of list environment or
>   or immediately before or immediately after one. It is OK to follow a
>   list if there is a blank line (`\par`) in between.
>
> [...]
>
> `\linewidth` is now adjusted within the wrapped text, but since it can
>   only be set for whole paragraphs at a time, it will persist with the
>   wrong value after the wrapping, until the paragraph is finished.

And at page 2:

> For esthetic reasons, only plain text should wrap around the figure.
>   Section titles and big equations look bad; lists are bad if the figure
>   is on the left. (All these function properly, they just don’t look
>   very good.) Small equations look fine.

Thus: Put a `\par` before `\begin{formel}`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{mdframed}

\newtheoremstyle{mystyle}{}{}{}{}{}{}{0.5em}{}
\theoremstyle{mystyle}
\newmdtheoremenv{formel}{Formel}

%\usepackage{picins}

\begin{document}
\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{8cm}
  \includegraphics[scale=0.48]{example-image-a}
\end{wrapfigure}
text 
\par
\makeatletter
\loop
\ifnum\c@WF@wrappedlines>3
\hspace*{1sp}\newline
\advance\c@WF@wrappedlines by -1
\repeat
\makeatother
\par
\begin{formel}[Formel]
$1+1=2$
\end{formel}
\end{document}
```

If the text to be wrapped is too short, the formula would be placed in the wrapped text, where it has the smaller width, of course. (And an additional `\usepackage{picins}` is needed, otherwise the formula is printed "over" the picture.) Using `\c@WF@wrappedlines` of the wrapfig package and automatically inserting the appropriate number of empty lines fixes this.

Answer (score 0):

Enclose the `wrapfig` in a `minipage`. Usualy

```
\begin{minipage}
\begin{wrapfig}
...
\end{wrapfig}
...text... to be wrapped
\end{minipage}
..more text which should be normal
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.