# wrong indentation after wrapfigure

Tags: wrapfigure

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to wrap text around a figure?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/291/how-to-wrap-text-around-a-figure)
>   [Textwidth wrong after wrapfigure](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67690/textwidth-wrong-after-wrapfigure)

I have the following problem: I used wrapfigure to include a floating picture. But the problem is, that the following formula is also affected by the textwidth of the wrapfigure, so the graphic goes not over a full line, but only the half textwidth, which is set in the wrapfigure!

Heres my code

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{wrapfigure}
\usepackage{shadethm}
\usepackage{mdframed}

\newtheoremstyle{mystyle}
  {\topsep}{\topsep}{}{}%
  {\bfseries}{:}{.5em}{}%

\theoremstyle{mystyle}

\newmdtheoremenv[hidealllines=true,backgroundcolor=red,skipabove=\topsep,
skipbelow=\topsep]{example}{Example}

\newmdtheoremenv[hidealllines=true,
backgroundcolor=blue,skipabove=\topsep,
skipbelow=\topsep]{formula}{Formula}


\begin{document}

\subsection{Subsection with wrapfigure}
text text text text wich goes around the picture text text text text text text text 
\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{0.5\textwidth}
  \begin{center}
    \includegraphics[scale=1]{picure.png}%width=0.48\textwidth
  \end{center}
  \caption{Caption}
\label{fig:zins}
\end{wrapfigure}

\noindent text text text

\begin{formel}[formula name] \label{geom}
$\\ \x + y +h+f+d+s+c+x+c+s+e+w+q+d+s+d+e=2323232323 +231231231 = 44$\\
or\\
$\bar{x}_{Geom}=\sqrt[n]{\frac{end}{begin}}$
\end{formel}
text text text text text text text text text text
\end{document}
```

So as I said, the formula looks wrong, it is just written over half the space, like the textwidth set in wrapfigure, when I add a

```
\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{0cm}\end{wrapfigure}
```

before the formula, then the formula is correct, but the following indentation of text and items is wrong?

**OK, the solution: add \par before, thanks!**

Comment: Welcome! Seems to be equal: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67690/textwidth-wrong-after-wrapfigure

Comment: thanks, solution: add \par before

thanks a lot ! I added the solution above, because I cannot answer my own question, but I think it is ok

Comment: @Gunomirious You will be able to answer your own question, but there is a time delay. Please come back in a little while and do this: the site works best if questions and answers are 'correctly' places, as we all know where to look for them.